# image quality issue while download layout as a image

Tags: android, image

my requirement is to download the image, it's work pretty well but the image quality is not good after downloading as an image

I am showing `Textview` inside the image and it's quality not maintain in image

I don't know anything about to maintain image quality please suggest me

**layout file**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".PreviewActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnimg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:foreground="@drawable/scrim"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgquote"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewpreview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/scrim"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quote"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="Quotes"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/author"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:padding="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:text=" -Author"
            android:textColor="#80EFEFEF"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#50585757"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnsetwallpaper"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgsetwallpaper"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set Wallpaper"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"/>
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lndownload"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgsave"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/downloadnew"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Download"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"/>
</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>


<ProgressBar
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my code
**java file**

```
lndownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            lnimg.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            lnimg.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bitmap = lnimg.getDrawingCache();

            saveImageToExternalStorage(bitmap);


        }
    });

 private void saveImageToExternalStorage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {
    String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/Inspiquo/Inspiquo Images");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
    File file = new File(myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists())
        file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(PreviewActivity.this, new String[]{file.toString()}, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                }
            });

    Toast.makeText(PreviewActivity.this, "Saved to Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

please help me to handle image quality

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Why do you modify the image? Why don't you just run a download that does not change the file?

Comment: And what does the line `finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out)` do?

Comment: And this is why you **NEVER** copy/paste code you don't understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are compressing bitmap remove this line

```
finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out)
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to not to use getDrawingCache

Try below method.

```
 private Bitmap getBitmapFromLayout()
   {

    Bitmap mBitmap = null;
            try {
                if (mBitmap != null) {
                    mBitmap.recycle();
                }
                mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(YOUR_LAYOUT_ID.getWidth(), YOUR_LAYOUT_ID.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
                paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
                YOUR_LAYOUT_ID.draw(canvas);
                canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
                return mBitmap;
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                System.gc();
            }
            return mBitmap;
}
```